# Website is not opening/loading in FireFox or IE

Tags: php, html

This site, a simple 5 page site,[[1](http://www.johnleftwich.co.uk/index.php)] with a form on the home page and a redirected 'thank you' page.

It will open and work in Chrome and Safari but doesn't work in Firefox and IE. Although it works with the "thank you" html and PHP removed.

```
An .htaccess file has the contents:
*Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.html /index.php*
```

The code originated from a W3C Schools example.
Is there a quick fix?

Thanks for your comments. The link to the w3c schools is [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp) There is nothing else in the .htaccess file other than quoted. My edited code is here:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"])) {

                $body = "Name : " . $_POST['name'] . "\n\rEmail : " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\rComment : " . $_POST['comment'] ;

                mail("j.leftwich@btinternet.com", "Form to email message", $body, "From: an@email.address"); 
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="john leftwich, cool illustration, ideas, illustration, artwork, technical, cartoons, brackley, england, unique"/>
<meta name="description" content="Worked in the graphic arts field for ever and am happy to work free of charge for non profit-making and charitable organisations, and 'mates' of course"/>
<title>John Leftwich</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock Salt">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="newfont">John Leftwich</div>
<p></p>
<!--navbar-->
    <ul id="nav"> 
 <div id="anothernewfont">
 <li class="currentpage">HOME</li>
 <li><a href="sketching.html">SKETCH BOOK</a></li>
    <li><a href="technical.html">TECHNICAL</a></li>
    <li style="white-space:nowrap"><a href="life.html">LIFE DRAWING</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">COVERS</a></li>
 </div>
</ul>
    <!--</div><!--END navbar-->
<p> Click for larger images . . .</p>
<!--top page images-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/busart.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 <img src="images/reception1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/cartoon1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 <img src="images/witney.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(6)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/latojg.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 <img src="images/map1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(7)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/lockgates.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 <img src="images/cuttings.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(8)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  
</div>
<!--END of top page images-->
<div id="textpara">
  <p style="line-height:1.4em">I have spent my working life in the graphic arts field and am happy to work free of charge for non profit-making and charitable organisations, and 'mates' of course! Please use the form below to contact me.</p>
  </div>
  
  <?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

header("Location: {$_POST["redirect"]}");

?>
<!--START form-->
<div style="width:320px; margin:auto">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<br>  
  <p>Name:<br>
  <input style="background-color:#f2f2f2" type="text" name="name" size="48" value="">
  </p>
  <p>Your email address here:<br>
  <input style="background-color:#f2f2f2" type="email" name="email" size="48" value="" >
  </p>
  <p>Comment:<br>
  <textarea style="background-color:#f2f2f2" name="comment" rows="5" cols="37"> </textarea>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></p>
  
  
 <!--extra bit added--> 
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.johnleftwich.co.uk/thank_you_page.html">
<!--extra bit ends-->
 
</form>
</div>
<!--END form-->

<!--START footer-->
<div style="width:96%;margin-top:30px; border-bottom:1px solid #000099">
<div style="float:left"><p style="line-height:0em">Site host: <a class="text" href="http://www.selectinternet.co.uk">Select Internet</a><br></div>
<div style="float:right; text-align:right"><p style="line-height:0em">January 2017<br></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<!--END footer-->
<!--START lightbox-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  
  <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()"><img src="images/button.png "/></span>
 
 <img class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)" src="images/arrownext.png" />
 <img class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)" src="images/arrowprev.png" />
 
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/busart_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/cartoon1_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/latojg_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/lockgates_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
 
 <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">5 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/reception1_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
 
 <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">6 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/witney_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
 
 <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">7 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/map1_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
 
 <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">8 / 8</div>
      <img src="images/cuttings_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="columnlower">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/busart.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Disaster Management Course brochure illustration">
    </div>
    <div class="columnlower">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/cartoon1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Bankers' &quot;loadsamoneyland&quot; and Dave Cameron">
    </div>
    <div class="columnlower">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/latojg.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Cover illustration for Land's End to J O'Groats Walk book">
    </div>
    <div class="columnlower">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/lockgates.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Canal lock gates sketch">
    </div>
 
 <div class="columnlower">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/reception1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Business reception area">
    </div>
    <div class="columnlower">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/witney.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Witney tennis club logo">
    </div>
    <div class="columnlower">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/map1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(7)" alt="Map for Murder for thr Truth book">
    </div>
    <div class="columnlower">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="images/cuttings.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(8)" alt="Newspaper cuttings">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Site seems to be stuck in a 302 redirect loop. Can you show us some code?

Comment: Can you provide any more information? Are there any other lines to the .htaccess file? Can you link to the W3C example?

Answer (score 0):

because there is a loop
i can see when i want to open website first route my connection to index.html
and then redirect me to index.php but here in index.php also redirect me again in index.php 
there is some mistake in your index.php  or your .htaccess file